# SOLR 7.7 - Concatenation giving unknown field error message

Tags: solr, concatenation, field

```
I have a SOLR core with more than 300 fields for each records. I have a requirement to concatenate two fields to produce a new value.

The two fields are

case_stone_color-en_US_s
top_ring_stone_color-en_US_s

I am using below method to concatenate in "fl" field
concat(case_stone_color-en_US_s, top_ring_stone_color-en_US_s)
```

http://localhost/solr/Core1/select?fl=concat(case_stone_color-en_US_s%20top_ring_stone_color-en_US_s)&fq=season-en_US_s%3AHoliday&fq=year-en_US_s%3A2019&q=*%3A*

```
But I am getting below error message

"metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"undefined field: \"case_stone_color\"",
    "code":400}}
```

Comment: could you please share the schema.xml?

Comment: I don't have schema created in the SOLR core. I am using using SOLR managed schema.

Comment: It's not adviced to use the managed schema in production, if you are planning to use the same in production environment... it's ok to use for development environment...if you could share the managed schema, it would be helpful to resolve this issue

Comment: I am not able to copy the managed xml file due to the size the limitation. I am using SOLR 7.4.0. Here is the link from github for the managed schema link    https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/example/files/conf/managed-schema